# Python ImportError / ModuleNotFoundError on own package in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, import, pydev

**Solved, thanks!**

Let's say I have a self-written module located under `C:\mymodules\general` which contains the files `foo.py` and `__init__.py`.

Now I want to import the function `bar()`, which is located inside `foo.py`, into a script in a completely different place.

Why is this not working?

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\mymodules")
from general import foo

foo.bar()
```

I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'`

The same if I add `C:\mymodules\general` to the path, instead.

Alternatively, I have also tried

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\mymodules")
import general.foo

foo.bar()
```

Here, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'general.foo'; 'general' is not a package`.

Why would general not be a package? I thought the requirement was "contains an `__init__.py`" (and the module I want to import, of course)?

This is all Python3, using PyDev in Eclipse under Windows7.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to do it instead?

---

**Edit:** the file is, indeed, already called `__init__.py`, so that is not the problem.

`__init__.py` already contains the line

```
__all__ = ["foo"]
```

**Edit 2:** Weirdly enough, the following works:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\mymodules")
from general import *
bar()
```

I really don't want to do `import *`, though. Surely there must be a cleaner way?

---

**Edit 3:** When I run it from IDLE, it works! (The first code, that is.) But in Eclipse PyDev, I still get the same error. Why?

Ah! Solution found! (see answer below, to close this).

Comment: the file needs to be `__init__.py` - with 2 underscores on either side

Comment: @RobinZigmond it already is, just misstated in the text, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: add `__init__.py` at root above `general`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Did not work, same result. (Also, putting answers into answers instead of comments would be helpful for the whole upvoting/downvoting/accepting business to work.)

Comment: yeah but we should answer only if we are pretty sure :) and `__init__.py` works empty for me. that tells interpreter to treat directories and files as modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. *headdesk*

In PyDev's Pythonpath (configured for the whole workspace), I had another package that contains a *module* called `general.py`. The interpreter found this before it got to my *package* `general`, so the message `general is not a package` referred to the *module* of the same name.

That should teach me to use separate workspaces when I do need to reuse existing names. And ideally, not to use the same name for different things, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When using `init` file, it has to be with underscores as Robin Zigmond says.

`__init__.py`

if that doesn't work for you, you may try writing in the `init` file

```
 from foo import bar
```

or

```
 from foo.py import *
```

[Look here](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)

Comment: It's never good to import all functions in a file. And it's from foo import bar.

Comment: The file is already named `__init__.py` (sorry, I edited the question to accomodate for this). It also contains the `__all__` variable. Having to import every single function into `__init__.py` sounds unpractical for a library?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Agreed. So how to do it better?